# How to be clear about Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

Can anyone please give any doc link or video which I can refer to get a good understanding of Dependency Injection(preferably using Autofac or StructureMap).
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: This is what Google is for.  Requests for off-site resources are off-topic for SO.

Comment: how are the asp and mvc tags related to this question?

Comment: They aren't.  OP spammed the tags.

Comment: By all means, read [this book](https://manning.com/seemann/).

Answer (score 1):

First try and understand the principle of DI **without** a DI container like AutoFac or StructureMap, sometimes called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), then you might find *what* a DI container's purpose is, which might help in gaining an understanding of the whole process

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection?rq=1) answers what DI is quite well.

DI containers are just libraries for automating the process of creating your object graphs.